# Question about invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be a vector space, $dim(V) = n$, and $T: V \rightarrow V$ is an isomorphism. Suppose there is an invertible $n \times n$ matrix $P$. Does there exist a basis $\beta$ of $V$ such that $[T]_{\beta} = P$?

Comment: Try with standard basis

Comment: @Jay maa In an abstract vector space there is no such thing as a standard basis

Comment: I think since T is an isomorphism, we can derive a new basis gamma such that gamma = {T(v1), T(v2), ..., T(vn)}. Then in this case, the matrix written in beta and gamma coordinate is an identity matrix.  We split the matrix [T]_beta into the product of two matrices, one of them is the change of coordinates matrix, and the other is already an identity matrix. So P must somehow equal to the change of coordinates matrix

Comment: That's what I get until now

Comment: This long comment should be a part of the *question*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. Take the special case where $T$ is the identity map. Then no matter what basis you pick, the matrix representation of $T$ will always be the identity matrix.

One particular counterexample would be

$P = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

$n = 2$

$T = $ the identity map.

Comment: This is generalized for any isomorphic linear transformation

Comment: So you cannot pick T

Comment: @Harry I'm saying for some choices of $V$, $T$, and $P$ this is true, and for other choices of $V$, $T$, and $P$ it is false. To show that it is sometimes false, I only need to come up with a single counterexample.

Comment: Yeah, but in this case the question asks about the choice of basis, not the linear transformation

Comment: @Harry The question is: "Does there exist a basis $\beta$ such that $[T]_\beta = P$?" My answer to this question is: in the case where $P$, $n$, and $T$ are as given in my answer, there does not exist such a $\beta$.

Answer (score 0):

A matrix $M$ representing $T$ in any basis must satisfy the same polynomials that $T$ does: in particular its minimal polynomial must be the same.  So e.g. $M = \pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 0 & 1\cr}$ has minimal polynomial $(x-1)^2$, and can only represent $T$ if
$(T-I)^2 = 0$ and $T \ne I$.